# Passing integer to other activity failed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a quiz application. The user selects an answer, and then clicks the "verify" button (in my program is button13). If the answer is wrong, it redirects it to another intent where a sad face is displayed; when he clicks the sad face (which is actually a button with an image as background) it returns him to the previous activity. The problem is that he is allowed to have only 3 chances, after that the program will close. I've tried to implement this, but I don't know where I am wrong...

I've declared a global variable in the main activity:

```
int contor;
```

Then, this is the button from the main activity:

```
final Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);

button13.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

//....checking the answer....

//if the answer is wrong
               if(contor == 3) //if the user has reached the maximum available answers, then exit

                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                        else
                    {
                        contor = contor + 1;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstGame1.this, TryAgain.class);
                        intent.putExtra("integerNumber", contor);
                        startActivity(intent);

//retrieve once again the number of incorrect answers from the second activity

                        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
                        int v2 = mIntent.getIntExtra("integerNumber", 0);
                        contor = v2;

                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked count is"+ contor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

And this is the second activity:

```
final Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button7.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

//get the number of incorrect answers from the previous activity

            Intent mIntent = getIntent();
            int v2 = mIntent.getIntExtra("integerNumber", 0);

         //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked count is"+ v2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(TryAgain.this, FirstGame1.class);

//send the number of incorrect answers back to the first activity

            intent.putExtra("integerNumber", v2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I've tried to use Toast to see the results. On the first wrong answer, it displays:

```
0 (in the second activity)
1 (in the main activity)
```

After the second wrong answer, it displays:

```
1 (in the second activity)
1 (in the main activity)
```

And it sticks to this results no matter how many wrong answers it gets.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Intent mIntent = getIntent() in the else will read the value in the intent of the first activity that contains 0 for the counter

Comment: you should not be using mIntent for local variables. the suffix m is only for member variable and BTW not many people like it anymore.

Comment: Use different keys while sending or receiving data i.e.integerNumber for specific operation

Comment: You send the counter to TryAgain activity and then you read it in the main activity. Or are they the same? It is not clear

Comment: @kingston yes, they are the same... I don't know how to increase the value of the counter (contor) correctly. For example, if I remove all the parsing data (I just open the new activity and then come back to the previous one, without sending any variables), the counter (contor) value will always be 1. I'm looking for a way to increase the contour value every time the user is send to the second activity (in my current state, the value of the counter is reinitialized every time the user is sent back to the first activity).

Comment: consider that if you send another intent to an activity that has already been started, getIntent will still return the old intent (the first one received by the activity). You need to call setIntent if you want to overwrite the intent

Comment: ok, i found the mistake... i just had to use a static global variable... sorry for the trouble

Comment: you should not be using static global vaiable: it's normally a bad idea

Comment: You can use this library for easy data sharing: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

**MainActivity**

```
     button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            contor++;

            if(contor  > 3) {
                Log.d("===>>>", "Reached three tries");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent secondIntent = new Intent(TryAgain.this, FirstGame1.class);
                startActivity(secondIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Second Activity**

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button7)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

`contor` is a member variable in MainActivity class